# PyCharm не распознает библиотеку, хотя она установлена (OC Windows 10)

Tags: pycharm

Всем привет! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с тем, что PyCharm не распознает библиотеку, хотя она установлена? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это починить? Кстати если не обращать внимание на ошибки, то код запускается и отрабатывает.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Если навести на подчеркнутый красным pandas, что пишет?

Answer (score 0):

Не силен именно в PyCharm, но наличие папки `venv` в проекте, говорит, что используется виртуальное пространство. То есть в глобальной установке `pandas` существует, а в виртуальном нет. Или наоборот.

1. Убедитесь, что в папке `venv/Lib/site-packages` у вас присутствует `pandas`
2. Если его там нет, установите этот пакет для виртуального пространства
3. Знайте точно, какое пространство используете в данный момент
4. Я использую только терминал для манипуляции с `venv`. Установку и проверку наличия пакетов делаю через терминал. Команды `pip freeze`, `pip list`, `pip install` и прочее, если вы испольузете `pip`, а не `conda` например

Comment: К сожалению не получатся решить проблему, скорее всего дело даже не в виртуальном окружении, а в  чем-то еще. Я создал новый проект и в нем выбрал интерпретатор питона, который установлен на компе, но проблема осталась.

Comment: @Ivan если просто открыть командную строку в винде, потом, зайти в python и импортировать pandas, будет ошибка?

Comment: не пробовал, думаю дело не в том, как устанавливать библиотеку, а в том что сам pycharm глючит, я уже и python, и pycharm переустановил, не помогает. Главное что код запускается не смотря на ошибки и отрабатывает корректно. Пришел к выводу, что нужно просто смириться и привыкать к новым реалиям, спасибо)

Comment: Если библа стоит в виртуальном окружении, то надо выбирать интерпретатор оттуда. Вообще я из VS Code, и там в папке `.vscode` лежит конфиг всего этого. Уверен что в PyCharm тоже есть подобное